# How to share a netty thread pool in Quarkus application

Tags: netty, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

According to completed 'Issues' in the Quarkus project on Github it should be possible to configure Quarkus application to use a predefined Netty threadpool instead of letting Quarkus framework to create it's own.

I have a project based on Quarkus, Vertx and Aws SDK v2 and I want to make sure the netty pool my AWS SDK client uses is the one used by other other libraries.

I want to do this so I can monitor the shared pool and implement my AWS SDK client so that it does not overload the pool by scheduling too many tasks.

Comment: Which issue are you referring to?

Comment: This one would suggest there is a way to get a reference to the pool quarkus is using and share with other libs - this issue was resolved with vertx specifically https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/3083

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to use the Event Loop Quarkus configures to pass it to some other library?

Comment: Ideally I would want to configure my own Event Loop Group and pass it to quarkus, vertx  and aws sdk. If thats not an option then at least would like to obtain a reference to the one quarkus configures and re-use it in aws sdk as well.

Comment: You can't configure your own, we own it :)